# Why is Type.GetType() not working on this string?

Tags: c#

When I do ToString() on a Type object, I get back this string. However, when I call GetType on the same string, I'm getting a null value. How do I fix this?

```
Type type1 = obj.GetType();
string str = type1.ToString(); //Returns A+B+CGeneric`1+D[E+F]

Type type2 = Type.GetType(str); //Returns null
```

Does it have something to do with the (+) signs instead of (.)?

Edit -
I'm trying to avoid calling fullname because it returns the version number. In the future if the version number changes, I will have trouble deserialzing the object with the type name.

Comment: A quick look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) answers this.  The input string is not a fully qualified name, because `type.ToString()` doesn't return a fully qualified type name.

Comment: What if the class definition changes along with the version number?  You want to deserialize some data into a class that has been modified while overlooking those modifications?

Comment: @Deadzone sorry had a typo

Comment: @Amy unfortunalty for now that is the requirement.

Comment: The version number isn't used when loading a type unless your assembly is given a strong-name.  Does your assembly use strong-naming?

Comment: @amy yep we use strong naming

Comment: Then you must use the version.  To ensure you can deserialize in the future, keep versioned assemblies around.

Answer (score 1):

You need to obtain the full name of the type including the namespace:

```
var typeName = obj.GetType().FullName;
Type type2 = Type.GetType(typeName);
```

Comment: Using `type.AssemblyQualifiedName` would be better.

Comment: @user3587180 the code in your question shows you getting the name of a type and immediately querying for that type by the name.  Now it sounds like serialization is involved.  That's an important detail you should include in the question, along with any other pertinent context.

Comment: @user3587180 Your code seems completely artificial, why would you try to obtain the type by name if you already did that on the first line `Type type1 = obj.GetType();`?

Answer (score 0):

Insetead of `.ToString()` use the [Type.FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Type.AssemblyQualifiedName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

The `FullName` does not contains version of assembly. That part is in `AssemblyQualifiedName`.